# Access ID update when using tickboxes

Tags: ms-access

I'm running this hotel database where in the pool there are 3 ID's in which people may have asked for a towel, asked and given it back, and not ask at all.

I'm using checkboxes to change the ID of the situation, but when i use the Checkbox, it updates the ID information and doesn't change the ID itself.

What should i do?

Comment: please show the code necessary to reproduce the problem. if there is no VBA code involved, show at least the schema and the checkbox databinding properties.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use 3 independent checkboxes. Options to consider:

1. combobox bound to field where data must be saved
2. radio buttons in an OptionGroup frame. Presuming the status indicators are 1, 2, 3 all you have to do is set OptionValue property of each radio button and bind frame to field where data must be saved.